# Is there a way to turn off the display of helmets for my companions?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Ideally, I'd like a solution that allows me to keep helm display on for my own character, but could accept a setting that is all or nothing.

As it stands, the "Show/Hide Helmet" option in preferences seems to affect my PC, but not my companions, and Kaliyo looks really stupid in a gas mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the Character Sheet (C)
2. Switch to the tab for your companion (make sure they are active/present)
3. Hit the "Customize Appearance" button on the middle right
4. Check "Hide Head Slot"

I'm not sure exactly when this was added but it's been at least a few months.

Answer (score 3):

There are [dozens of threads](https://www.google.com/search?q=hide%20companion%20helmet%20swtor#hl=en&q=+site:swtor.com+hide+companion+helmet+swtor&sa=X&ei=dLkDT-73C7TViAKMkKzJDg&ved=0CCsQrQIwAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=bc16b5ab8d851553&biw=1920&bih=1075) on this issue, but to date (3 January 2012) there is no way to hide your companion's Helm.

You are limited to:

1. Choosing a helm with limited model (as @Krazer suggests)
2. Having your companion not wear a helm