# Is it possible to get a hat that won't mess up my awesome mohawk?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I know the prospects aren't good, but are there any hats available (especially for smugglers) that would allow me to keep my wonderful Mohawk?

[image]

Comment: This question clearly needs a screenshot of the mohawk.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to turn off the display of helmets for my companions?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/45448/6066)

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you want the helm to still be displayed?

There are certain types of hats that don't hide your hair such as ["headgear" pieces](http://www.torhead.com/search/headgear).

However, even in this list there are pieces that will cover your entire head and hide the hair.

The only other option is to [hide all helm graphics through the preferences menu](http://tortips.com/swtor-how-to-hide-helmet-mask-or-hood/):

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming that even if I hide helm graphics, it'll still show up for other people. My 'hawk is too awesome to keep it only for myself. (; This is a good start though, thanks!

Comment: If you hide your helm graphics it won't show to other people.

Answer (score 2):

As Sorean mentioned there are certain types of headgear that do not cover your hair. I have a facemask style on my Warrior.

[image: I'm only half of vader!]

I would suggest finding and orange one you like and gearing it as you level. that's one of the great things about orange gear, you pick the look and stack the stats to match what you want.

Here is a TorHead list of [Medium Armor orange headgear](http://www.torhead.com/items/catg/2/subcatg/2/quality/4/slot/9/page/2). Blues are included but that is how Swtor defines them.

Some that look promising (no pics on Torhead yet):

- [sniper-elite-headgear](http://www.torhead.com/item/a6XK5FH/sniper-elite-headgear)
- [ablative-lacqerous-headgear](http://www.torhead.com/item/e7Ro0un/ablative-lacqerous-headgear)
- [furious-assault-headgear](http://www.torhead.com/item/apvfMoe/furious-assault-headgear)
- [rd-05a-close-quarters-headgear](http://www.torhead.com/item/7Wzb6VE/rd-05a-close-quarters-headgear)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a sith assassin with an awesome Mohawk aswell, but as i wear cloth, you have some crowns and such you can wear, that still keep the vibe going. So what you can do is get an orange cloth helm (or crown), strip it and place in your own stuff.

(I haven't checked this out tho, but i think it is also possible to not make your helm shown.)